# Prophet - R - Not working

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I'm a newbie at `R` and I am stuck with an issue.
I have used the `Prophet` Package to forecast values but it is not working for obscure reasons I don't understand.

Here is my code :

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("prophet")

library(dplyr)
library(prophet)

data2 <- read.csv("Eyeballs daily 2015 - 2016 - Sheet1.csv")
data2$daily <- as.Date(data2$daily)

december <-data_frame (
holiday='december',
ds=as.Date(c('2012-12-22','2013-12-21','2014-12-20','2015-12-09','2016-
12-17','2017-12-23','2018-12-22','2019-12-21','2020-12-19')),
lower_window=0,
upper_window=14
)

februarya <-data_frame (
holiday='februarya',
ds=as.Date(c('2013-02-23','2014-03-01','2015-02-07','2016-01-13','2017-
02-18','2018-02-10','2019-02-16','2020-02-15','2021-02-06')),
lower_window=0,
upper_window=14 
) 

februaryb <- data_frame (
holiday='februaryb',
ds=as.Date(c('2013-02-16','2014-02-22','2015-02-21','2016-02-06','2017-
02-11','2019-02-09','2020-02-08','2021-02-20')),
lower_window=0,
upper_window=14
)

februaryc <- data_frame (
holiday='februaryc',
ds=as.Date(c('2013-03-02','2014-02-15','2015-02-14','2016-02-20','2017-
02-04','2018-02-17','2019-02-23','2020-02-01','2021-02-13')),
lower_window=0,
upper_window=14
)

holidays <- bind_rows(december,februarya,februaryb,februaryc)

m <- prophet (data2, holidays = holidays)

future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 120, freq = "day")

forecast <- predict (m, future)
write.csv(forecast , "test.csv")
```

Eveything is working until this line of code

```
m <- prophet (data2, holidays = holidays)
```

The error is the following:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'y' not found.
```

Does someone know why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: Sorry guys, yes I get an error which is : Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'y' not found.

Comment: Please add it to your question

Comment: Are you sure that you define your variables correctly.

Comment: Prophet requires that your input dataframe should have columns called `ds` for dates and `y` for values, which I don't think yours currently does

Comment: @Relasta It is indeed the problem ! Thanks a lot for your help guys